# Using CDI + WS/RS + JPA to build an app

Tags: jpa, jakarta-ee, java-ee-6, jax-rs, cdi

```
@Path(value = "/user")
@Stateless
public class UserService {

    @Inject
    private UserManager manager;

    @Path(value = "/create")
    @GET
    @Produces(value = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String doCreate(@QueryParam(value = "name") String name) {
        manager.createUser(name);

        return "OK";
    }
}
```

here is the user manager impl

```
public class UserManager {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "shop")
    private EntityManager em;

    public void createUser(String name) {
        User user = new User();
        user.setName(name);
        // skip some more initializations 
        em.persist(user);
    }
}
```

the problem is if i do not mark UserService as @Stateless then the manager field is null

but if i mark @Stateless, i can have the manager field injected, and the application works as i can get the data saved into db

just wondering, what is the reason behind this?

and is this the preferred way to wiring the application?

well, i am thinking to pull out the EntityManager to a producer, so that it can be shared

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> the problem is if I do not mark UserService as @Stateless then the manager field is null

For injection to occur, the class has to be a *managed component* such as Enterprise Beans, Servlets, Filters, JSF managed beans, etc or **CDI managed bean** (this is the new part with Java EE 6, you can make any class a managed bean with CDI).

So, if you don't make your JAX-RS endpoint an EJB, how to enable injection? This is nicely explained in [JAX-RS and CDI integration using Glassfish v3](https://www.java.net/node/700437):

> There are two ways CDI managed beans
>   are enabled:
>
> 1. instantiated by CDI, life-cycle managed by Jersey. Annotate with
>      `@ManagedBean` and optionally annotate
>      with a Jersey scope annotation.
> 2. instantiated and managed by CDI. Annotate with a CDI scope annotation,
>      like `@RequestScoped` (no `@ManagedBean`
>      is required)

I also suggest checking the resources below.

> and is this the preferred way to wiring the application?

I'd say yes. CDI is very nice and... don't you like injection?

> well, I am thinking to pull out the EntityManager to a producer, so that it can be shared

Shared between what? And why? In you case, you should use an `EntityManager` with a lifetime that is scoped to a single transaction (a *transaction-scoped persistence context*). In other words, don't share it (and don't worry about opening and closing it for each request, this is not an expensive operation).

#### References

- JPA 2.0 Specification

  - Section 7.6 "Container-managed Persistence Contexts"
  - Section 7.6.1 "Container-managed Transaction-scoped Persistence Context"
  - Section 7.6.2 "Container-managed Extended Persistence Context"

#### Resources

- [Dependency Injection in Java EE 6 - Part 1](http://www.theserverside.com/news/1373391/Dependency-Injection-in-Java-EE-6-Part-1)
- [Introducing the Java EE 6 Platform: Part 1](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javaee/javaee6overview-141808.html)
- [TOTD #124: Using CDI + JPA with JAX-RS and JAX-WS](http://blogs.oracle.com/arungupta/entry/totd_124_using_cdi_jpa)

Comment: very nice and detailed answer, one more thing to clarify, the 'sharing' of the EM, suppose i have another OrderService which uses the same PU, i don't want to repeat the     @PersistenceContext(unitName = "shop") rather i'd want to have it as @Inject EntityManager, how could i do it?

Comment: @Dapeng AFAIK, you don't need to specify the `unitName` in `@PersistenceContext` if there is only one persistence unit defined in the scope of the component which is using `@PersistenceContext`, otherwise you need to specify it.

Answer (score 0):

The **@Singleton** annotation will help: http://www.mentby.com/paul-sandoz/jax-rs-on-glassfish-31-ejb-injection.html